# any object delegate from another class

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I want to ask one thing, let suppose I have one view controller which has table view button etc now i create `NSObject` class for table one `NSObject` class for button and place there delegates over there. Can I do this? If yes how?

Like I want to place table in "myviewcontroller" and i place tableview delegates in "mytable" nsobject class and call delegates from myviewcontroller class ?

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

Answer (score 0):

Just make your NSObject subclass delegate of UITableView and assign it to your tableView.

```
myTableController = [MyTableController alloc] init];
myTableView = [UITableView alloc] initWithStyle...];
myTableView.delegate = myTableViewController;
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that you have the access to both `UITableView` object (say `mTable`) and `UIButton` object (say `btn`)

in your viewDidLoad or any other method do like this

```
mTable.delegate = mytableObj;

[btn addTarget:mybutton action:@selector(btnClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```